# Margin-top pushes entire div down rather than just single element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button that is at the bottom of the div that I've created, however, once I use margin top on the element, it moves everything including the container that the button (element) is in too.

Here's what I have so far:

```
.background{
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 564px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/450x564) no-repeat;
}
.verify{
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
} 
.link{
    margin: 425px 0px 0px 80px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x41) no-repeat;
    width: 384px;
    height: 51px;
    position: relative;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="background">
      <p class="verify">Confirm your email by following the link below:</p>
      <div class="link"> 
        </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want the background class to be static while all the elements within the container to move freely when adjusting margins on them. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try positioning the child elements `absolute` inside the `relative` parent.

Comment: Maybe do you have some mockup to give us a clear idea?

Comment: @War10ck that was exactly it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [War19ck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680836/war10ck) recommends inside the comments to your question, you should position the child element (`.link`) **absolute** to its parent (`.background`):

```
.link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:80px;
    left:33px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x41) no-repeat;
    width: 384px;
    height: 51px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Notice:

- I removed the `padding`!
- You already set the parents position to `relative` (required)

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf4xL/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem! I had to set the parent to relative and individual elements to absolute. Thanks!